# Nginx returns 502 error when php-fpm returns 500

Tags: nginx, php, error-code

I'm running nginx with php-fpm.  Whenever my Symfony app crashes, it returns a 500 error with the debug info and stack traces I need.  The problem is Nginx dumps that info and returns a 502 error with no content.

How can I configure nginx to forward along the 500 error and content from php-fpm?

Answer (score 2):

You can use "proxy_intercept_errors on" to transfer error code to client.
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_intercept_errors

Answer (score 1):

If your Symfony app crashes before any content was returned, then there is no content.

Comment: No, I can see the prepared response with a debugger before the last line of code is executed (which essentialy prints the output).  PHP sets the header code to 500 and the content contains a standard xdebug stack trace.  The problem is, none of that comes out of nginx.

Comment: I don't know how php debugger works, and what it show to you. But nginx returns a 502 only if there is no valid data from upstream.

Comment: You can use tcpdump to check what is actually sent to nginx.

Comment: Or you can enable debug log in nginx to see what happens: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/debugging_log.html