# nginx gives 502 for non handled exception 500 error in flask

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi

I am running a Flask application and using uwsgi socket nginx configuration.

This may be a stupid question but the issue I am facing is that whenever there is exception raised in Flask code (non handled exception for example 1/0), my nginx gives 502 instead of 500. I wanted to know if raising the exception is not getting propagated to nginx as 500 from uwsgi unix socket by default or do I need to specify this explicitly? Somewhere I read that for exceptions, Flask doesn't raise 500 error message automatically. Any comments will be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21784601/nginx-returns-502-error-when-php-fpm-returns-500

Comment: This question has nothing to do with php. It was about uwsgi and flask.

Comment: I know you’re using Flask, but that question is not specific to php. It’s about nginx configuration and forwarding errors. Or as the answer suggests below, make sure you’re properly providing a valid response back to nginx from your app.

Comment: I'll recheck my ini file to see if I have missed something. I'll post my findings in sometime.

Comment: @JeffStorey Makes sense. I am going to do that change and will post my findings in sometime. Thanks. Appreciate it.

Comment: Big Thanks @JeffStorey. Your post helped me. See solution below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the 502 spec:

> The HyperText Transfer Protocol 502 Bad Gateway server error response
>   code indicates that the server, while acting as a gateway or proxy,
>   received an invalid response from the upstream server.

If your app responds anything while hitting an exception, it's most likely garbage and nginx raises (correctly) the 502, meaning "I won't (as opposed to can't) talk to the backend".

If you want 500s, you have to catch any possible underlying exception, wrap it in a valid response and it will be processed by nginx.

Comment: Exactly, this is what I am facing. I think I'll have to wrap any error response so that NGINX can read it. I have to try @Jeff Storey solution where I can propagate the error to NGINX.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was able to solve this issue. Thanks to @Jeff Storey and @joppich.

My proxy server was not able to read the response from by backend server which was causing this issue. I added an interceptor to catch all exceptions and propagate it to NGINX via uwsgi using the nginx `proxy_intercept_errors on;`. Big thanks Jeff and joppich. Appreciate your help.